# Quarterly process to validate all logins

Tags: sql-server, validation, authentication

Can anyone help me with a query for quarterly process that can validate all logins in SQL server ? We also need to find logins that have too much privileges, correct them or document exceptions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define too much privileages..best bet would be create a sql job which runs every quarter or store the data in database.

below script gives object level perms as well,taken from [TechNet](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-logins-databases-816f66b2)

```
--Server level Logins and roles
SELECT sp.name AS LoginName,sp.type_desc AS LoginType, sp.default_database_name AS DefaultDBName,slog.sysadmin AS SysAdmin,slog.securityadmin AS SecurityAdmin,slog.serveradmin AS ServerAdmin, slog.setupadmin AS SetupAdmin, slog.processadmin AS ProcessAdmin, slog.diskadmin AS DiskAdmin, slog.dbcreator AS DBCreator,slog.bulkadmin AS BulkAdmin
FROM sys.server_principals sp  JOIN master..syslogins slog
ON sp.sid=slog.sid 
WHERE sp.type  <> 'R' AND sp.name NOT LIKE '##%'

--Databases users and roles
DECLARE @SQLStatement VARCHAR(4000) 
DECLARE @T_DBuser TABLE (DBName SYSNAME, UserName SYSNAME, AssociatedDBRole NVARCHAR(256)) 
SET @SQLStatement='
SELECT ''?'' AS DBName,dp.name AS UserName,USER_NAME(drm.role_principal_id) AS AssociatedDBRole 
FROM ?.sys.database_principals dp
LEFT OUTER JOIN ?.sys.database_role_members drm
ON dp.principal_id=drm.member_principal_id 
WHERE dp.sid NOT IN (0x01) AND dp.sid IS NOT NULL AND dp.type NOT IN (''C'') AND dp.is_fixed_role <> 1 AND dp.name NOT LIKE ''##%'' AND ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''msdb'',''model'',''tempdb'') ORDER BY DBName'
INSERT @T_DBuser
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @SQLStatement
SELECT * FROM @T_DBuser ORDER BY DBName

--Get objects permission of specified user database 
USE <Database Name>
GO
DECLARE @Obj VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @T_Obj TABLE (UserName SYSNAME, ObjectName SYSNAME, Permission NVARCHAR(128))
SET @Obj='
SELECT Us.name AS username, Obj.name AS object,  dp.permission_name AS permission 
FROM sys.database_permissions dp
JOIN sys.sysusers Us 
ON dp.grantee_principal_id = Us.uid 
JOIN sys.sysobjects Obj
ON dp.major_id = Obj.id '
INSERT @T_Obj 
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @Obj
SELECT * FROM @T_Obj
```